# No hay proveedores de control de código fuente activos

Tags: git, github, vscode

Desde hace un tiempo que `Visual Studio Code` no me detecta `Git`, aunque lo tenga instalado.

Cuando accedo al control de fuentes sale el siguiente mensaje:

> No hay proveedores de control de código fuente activos

He probado lo siguiente sin obtener resultados satisfactorios:

- Desinstalar VS Code y volverlo a instalar
- Desinstalar VS Code, instalar Git e instalar VS Code
- Añadir a las variables globales la ruta de Git (esto está marcado como solución en SOen)

Tengo instalado tanto Git como el cliente de GitHub, con este último puedo trabajar directamente contra GitHub (a través de la interfaz de usuario). 
Pero Visual Studio Code no se "entera" que tengo un control de código instalado.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**Edición #1**

Añado la propuesta de solución pero sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He tardado en dar con la solución porque lo dejé pasar, pero he tenido que retomarlo y finalmente la encontré.

No es necesario, al menos en mi caso, tener que forzar la ruta del ejecutable en vcode, tan sólo es necesario borrar la carpeta que se genera en el directorio del usuario.

1. Windows + R y escribir `%appdata% ENTER`
2. En `\AppData\Roaming\` borrar la carpeta `Code`, con el IDE cerrado
3. Volver a abrir VCode y ya saldrá la interfaz para poder abrir un proyecto con git.

Nunca es tarde si la dicha es buena :)

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que tengas la configuracion abre Visual Studio Code:

Settings (File -> Preferences -> Settings)[en la parte derecha superior abre la opcion open setting json] modifica de la siguiente manera
en el path asegurate que tengas la ruta del ejecutable de git correctamente.

```
{
    // Is git enabled
    "git.enabled": true,

    // Path to the git executable
    "git.path": "C:\\path\\to\\git.exe"

}
```

Comment: Lo he añadido en el espacio de trabajo general, no del usuario. pero cuando añado la configuración me da un error en `git.enabled` y `git.path`: Unknow configuration settings. Añado una captura.